# undefined local variable or method for extended module

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

**NOTE:** the question was edited to reflect the issue.

i would like to work with [`knife-api`](https://github.com/andyglick/knife-api) rubygem. enclosed a snippet of my code

```
require 'chef'
require 'chef/knife'
require 'knife/api'

module X
  module Y
    module Z
      include Chef::Knife::API

      def self.foo
        resp = knife_capture :search, ['*:*']
        puts resp
      end
    end
  end
end
```

when `X::Y::Z.foo` is called, it returns

```
gems/knife-api-0.1.7/lib/knife/api.rb:41:in `ensure in knife_capture': undefined local variable or method `revert_io_channels' for X::Y::Z (NameError)
```

it appears that he enclosing scope functions (`Chef::Knife` within `knife-api`) are inaccessible within `X::Y::Z.foo`.

how should i make this work?

Comment: assuming `knife` comes from `Chef::Knife::API`, you can try `extend` instead of `include` to make it availbale to the _class methods_ (e.g. `self.foo`)

Comment: @maxpleaner: could you please make it an answer to be able to accept it?

Comment: @maxpleaner: your suggestion works only for the `knife` function, though when using `knife_capture` function, which in turn uses other functions from enclosing scope, such as `revert_io_channels` function, the following error is returned `NameError: undefined local variable or method `revert_io_channels' for X::Y:Module`. how may i include everything including enclosing scope (or enjoy its closure)?

Comment: Do not use that gem, use `chef-api`.

Comment: @coderanger: as always, thank you. could you please add an answer so i could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a complete non-answer, do not use the `knife-api` gem. It should not exist. The correct gem to use if you want to access Chef API data from Ruby code is `chef-api` (I know, we're real creative with names). If you want to do something very small, check out the `knife exec` command which just exposes the raw Chef object API (not as refined as `chef-api`, but built in).

Answer (score 0):

This gem is a fork of another project that is no longer maintained. Looking at the gem code, it appears there were several issues introduced to the latest version (`0.1.7`) through some bad refactoring of the original code. That version was released a year ago and it hasn't had any commits since. The repo also does not accept issue tickets, and it has no tests. If you must use this gem, I would try a pessimistic constraint `gem 'knife-api', '< 0.1.7'` and see if that works. However it might be a better idea to skip it entirely. I made an attempt to fix the issues and submit a PR. You can also try pulling the gem from my forked repo https://github.com/msimonborg/knife-api

Comment: tried it and it is not working (the same error remains)... :(

Comment: the same error that appears in my original post -- `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'revert_io_channels' for X::Y::Z:Module`

Comment: @MrRoth It looks like `revert_io_channels` is being defined as an instance method on the `Chef::Knife` class. That class is opened by the gem and that method is added directly to it. But when the `Chef::Knife::API` module is included, I don't think you're gaining access to those `Chef::Knife` methods in your scope. It seems like an issue with the gem. I wish I could dig deeper, but I can't at the moment, sorry

Comment: @MrRoth In other words, there are a few methods the gem should define in the `Chef::Knife::API` module, not the `Chef::Knife` class. Look at the original repo this gem was forked from. https://github.com/chef-workflow/knife-dsl/blob/master/lib/knife/dsl.rb#L30 The `revert_io_channels` method is an abstraction of processes that were originally in the `knife_capture` body. But  `revert_io_channels` is defined in a scope the module doesn't have access to. https://github.com/andyglick/knife-api/blob/master/lib/knife/api.rb#L41 This is my best guess at what's wrong

Comment: @MrRoth I dug a little more and updated the answer with a suggestion that I think should actually help. Let me know if it does